# multi-connection client socket application C++

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, winapi

I am developing an application that connects to different servers, collects the data and displays it.
Actually, I've already created it, but it feels like I made it horribly wrong because it creates a bunch of threads and I do understand that it is not scalable.

Right now I have the following logic (simplified c++ pseudocode):

```
// handles one connection
class Client
{
public:
    void start(); //opens socket, connects, starts threads
    void stop(); //closes socket, joins threads

    ClientState getState();
    void requestState();
private:
   thread _threadReceive; // runs "handleReceive()" in a loop
   thread _threadSend; // runs "handleSend()" in a loop
   thread _threadUpdate; // runs "update()" in a loop

   queue _commands;
   queue _replies;
   ClientState _currentState;

   void handleReceive(); // recv reply from server, push to "_replies"
   void handleSend(); // pops from "_commands", send to server
   void update(); // pops reply, processes it, updates current state

   //...
};
```

Then later I have the following:

```
//App's logic
class App
{
public:
    void start(); // init app, creates clients from config
    void stop(); // iterates over "_clients" and calls "stop()", joins threads
private:
    vector<Client> _clients;
    vector<ClientState> _clientStates;

    thread _threadUpdateClients;
    thread _threadRequestClients;

    void connect(); //iterate over "_clients" and "start()"; 
    void updateStates(); //iterate over "_clients" and fill "_clientStates" accordingly
    void requestStates(); //iterate over "_clients" and call "requestState()"
    void updateUi(); // iterate over "_clientStates" and display them

   //...
}
```

Obviously, this means having lots of locking and all sorts of ugly code to synchronize everything (which causes context switching). The most frustrating part is that it works and it grew in a successful application.

This code is a direct port of a .NET 4.5 C# code (it was my first actual multithreaded application.) that I wrote several years ago - I need to execute it on several Windows 2000 and XP SP1 machines.
I "sense" all it's problems, but I don't know how to implement it in a proper way. There are lots of simple client-server tutorials, but I've never found anything about patterns/architecture, program structure. I've also read a lot about select() and non-blocking sockets, but I got really confused:

- how to use select() correctly?
- how to organize state/data storages, queues, etc. with non-blocking sockets.
- Is it available on Windows XP, cause i've run into various problems with MSDN guides (several winsock functions were not available on 2000, XP, Vista).

I read about asio, libev implementations, but they hide the details and ultimately my lack of knowledge is exactly what got me into this situation. 
Right now I simply iterate and update all active connections, gather data and display, but I always felt like it is not a correct implementation.

Comment: There are *tons* of networking tutorials all over the Internet, many which includes using the Windows socket API (which isn't *that* different from the "standard" POSIX API). Most good ones of course includes how to use `select`.

Comment: Also, while you should definitely learn how sockets and networking works on a lower level, once you learned that scrap the code and go for higher-level API's or frameworks. Knowing what happens behind the scenes is good (and IMO mandatory) using higher-level frameworks makes ones life as a programmer much easier in the long run.

Comment: This question is off-topic. A better place to ask about architecture is [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @IInspectable when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using two threads, one is UI thread, one is network thread, in network thread, you can use asio or libev. data can be passed through queue or shared variables. and use condition variable or mutex to sync threads. you can reference pthread library and man select function.